# Ordering a string by text asc and numbers desc, from the same column in mysql

Tags: mysql, sorting

I would like to order a set like this:

- a 2
- a 1
- b 9

not like the normal ascending order:

- a 1
- a 2
- b 9

I other words, I have a single column with some text and sometimes a number i the end. I would like to have all the fields with a number in the end to be sorted descending on the numbers, but the leading text must still be sorted ascending.

The strings are not just 1 char long but of an unknown length and the numbers are also not only 1 char long, but also of an unknown length and not guaranteed to be in the end of the string it might look like: "Random event, 12th time"

If I have a string like "Random event, 12th time" I want it to appear before: "Random event, 11th time" in my result.

Hope there are some SQL guys who know the answer to this :)

Comment: and if you have `Random event, 12th time, 12th century`, it must be before `Random event, 12th time, 11th century` ?

Comment: Interesting question, no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could create a function that isolates the number you want to order by. eg. something like this (found here [MySQL strip non-numeric characters to compare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287105/mysql-strip-non-numeric-characters-to-compare))

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS STRIP_NON_DIGIT;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION STRIP_NON_DIGIT(input VARCHAR(255))
   RETURNS INT
   DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
   DECLARE output   VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '';
   DECLARE iterator INT          DEFAULT 1;
   WHILE iterator < (LENGTH(input) + 1) DO
      IF SUBSTRING(input, iterator, 1) IN ( '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' ) THEN
         SET output = CONCAT(output, SUBSTRING(input, iterator, 1));
      END IF;
      SET iterator = iterator + 1;
   END WHILE;
   RETURN output;
END
$$
```

and now run your sql like this:

SELECT * FROM myTable order by myString, STRIP_NON_DIGIT(myString) DESC;

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from table name where "your query " and  "  " order by asc;
```

or if in descending use  "dec" 
your column which you want to descending or ascending put in " "

Comment: What is `where "your query" "`?? and what is `and " "`? you didn't compare it to anything? and `order by ` what???

Comment: $query = "SELECT `msg`, `id`, `nick`, `date` FROM `entries` WHERE `ctg` = ? ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 15 OFFSET ?";

Comment: I don't think what you are suggesting is the solution to my problem. Please read my post and the comment below again or explain me why this solves my problem.