# PHP String Contains Integer

Tags: php, mysql

I've the following strings as follows :

```
1BG200,1M400,1BA1000
```

And I want to to compare the above strings into Desc Order...

Code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM collected WHERE c_no BETWEEN '".$from."' AND '".$to."' ORDER BY c_no Desc";
```

Output :

```
1M400
1BG200
1BA1000
```

It should be 1000 is larger, then 400, 200..How can i compare them ? I believe its not right to compare string that contains integer ! And I can't find a correct solution for my issue ?

Some people suggested using `preg_match` or `substr`..But as you can see there are single and double characters ex ( M and BG ).

Sorry, I'm not that familiar with PHP.. Please Help !

Comment: So, the only dependent part for the sorting algorithm is the ending digit sequence?

Comment: @Daniel Well I wanted to compare the full string, but it seems that its not working with me. So yea, i want to ignore the letters and sort digit sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a custom sort, looking only at the numerical part

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    $numa = intval(preg_replace('/[0-9]*[A-Z]+/', '', $a));
    $numb = intval(preg_replace('/[0-9]*[A-Z]+/', '', $b));
    if($a == $b) return 0;
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

//Now get the list and sort
usort($list, "cmp");
```

Comment: In addition if you'd want the leading digit to be part of the sorting algorithm as well you'd exchange the pattern for `"/[^0-9]/"` which will base the sorting on all the digits.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `preg_replace('/[0-9][A-Z]+/', '', $var)` to remove first number and more then one letter after, and then use php [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).

Answer (score 1):

You could add a custom function to your MySQL. Found one that looks like it could strip out all the non digit characters [MySQL strip non-numeric characters to compare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287105/mysql-strip-non-numeric-characters-to-compare).

I would highly recommend doing this over bringing everything back to php and sorting if you ever decide to use limit / offset due to large results being returned. Otherwise you would have to pull everything back to PHP then splice an array at which point I feel it would be an inefficient use of resources.

Alternatively, you could add a sort column to your table if that is a feasable option, to allow you to better utilize indexes in MySQL which depending on your record set may be a huge performance difference.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the user defined preg-functions to your mysql (https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg).
Then use PREG_CAPTURE in your order by clause.

Answer (score 0):

in general preg is expensive. To gain a number from the given pattern I would do something like this:

```
digitstri='1M400'; // just an example
number=intval(is_number(digitstri{2})?substr(digitstri,2):substr(digitstri,3))
```

I think, the sorting from there is clear...