# How to get the max value from a column with alphanumeric strings?

Tags: php, mysql, casting, substr

I have a table which contains invoice and estimate numbers.The invoice numbers are like `"IN1000","IN1001","IN1002"` and so on.The estimate numbers are like `"ES101","ES102","ES103"`.How can I get the max of both my invoice and estimate? I would also like it to be cast into an integer like 1000.

I have tried the following query:

```
SELECT Max(CAST (SUBSTR(invoiceNo,3) AS UNSIGNED)) FROM selected_items 
WHERE invoiceNo RLIKE 'IN';
```

When I run this query I get the following error :

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'UNSIGNED)) FROM selected_items WHERE invoiceNo RLIKE 'IN'' at
>   line 1.

And I am using similar approach for estimate :

```
SELECT Max(CAST (SUBSTR(invoiceNo,3) AS UNSIGNED)) FROM selected_items
WHERE invoiceNo RLIKE 'ES';
```

How can I do both the operations in one query? Any help is appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @FelixPamittan can you help with a solution?

Comment: No, I only saw this question because it showed up under a tag I follow.

Comment: I suspect that your `invoiceNo` column may have some extra characters in it.  This is why the `CAST` is failing.  Can you show us some sample data?

Comment: No problem thanks anyways @AaronBertrand

Comment: I recommend that you strip out alpha characters. Take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287105/mysql-strip-non-numeric-characters-to-compare

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes both invoice number and estimate number get saved in the same column  like "IN1000" and estimates like "ES100" how can I overcome this I am new to programming.

Comment: is the prefix constant or the same? is it always "IN" and "ES"?

Comment: @Ceeee yes the prefix will always be either "IN" or "ES" where "IN" stands for Invoice Number and "ES" stands for Estimate number.

Comment: you can get max value from alphanumeric column by breaking string in two variables (character ,number) then get order by desc value and again join them

Comment: @User can you provide a answer.Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your `invoiceNo` column has some extra characters which are still present even after you use `SUBSTR()`.  This is causing the `CAST` to fail because non numeric characters are still present.  If these extra characters be whitespace, then the `TRIM()` function might come in handy:

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(SUBSTR(TRIM(invoiceNo),3) AS UNSIGNED))
FROM selected_items 
WHERE invoiceNo RLIKE 'IN'
```

As @Tah pointed out, here is a link which might help you to remove *all* alphanumeric characters, if it comes to that:

[MySQL strip non-numeric characters to compare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287105/mysql-strip-non-numeric-characters-to-compare)

**Update:**

If you want to get both max values in one query, one way would be to do a `UNION` of the two queries you mentioned:

```
SELECT 'invoiceMax', MAX(CAST(SUBSTR(TRIM(invoiceNo),3) AS UNSIGNED))
FROM selected_items 
WHERE invoiceNo RLIKE 'IN'
UNION
SELECT 'estimateMax', MAX(CAST(SUBSTR(TRIM(invoiceNo),3) AS UNSIGNED))
FROM selected_items 
WHERE invoiceNo RLIKE 'ES'
```

Comment: Ya this works but how can I do the same thing for "ES" without writing a new query.

Comment: Thank you so much Tim :)

Answer (score 2):

As Suggested by @FuzzyTree and @TimBiegeleisen you can try the following query .

```
Select (SELECT MAX(CAST(SUBSTR(TRIM(invoiceNo),3) AS UNSIGNED))
FROM selected_items 
WHERE invoiceNo RLIKE 'IN') as maxIN,
(SELECT MAX(CAST(SUBSTR(TRIM(invoiceNo),3) AS UNSIGNED))
FROM selected_items 
WHERE invoiceNo RLIKE 'ES') as maxES;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine your queries using conditional aggregation:

```
select
    max(case when invoiceNo rlike 'IN' then (your value here) end) maxIn,
    max(case when invoiceNo like 'ES' then (your value here) end) maxEs
from selected_items
where invoiceNo rlike 'IN'
or invoiceNo like 'ES'
```

Another way is to use subqueries. I'm not sure which runs faster, so you might want to test both.

```
select
    (your in query) as maxIn,
    (your en query) as maxEn
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Fuzzytree :)

Answer (score 0):

```
// get max index value   codeinigter
        $res = $this->db->get($table)->result();
        $arr = array();
        foreach ($res as $val) {
            $str = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $val->id);
            $arr[] = $str;
        }
        $or = max($arr) + 1;
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it? Additionally, can you explain why you introduce PHP code to a question that is already answered multiple times with pure MySQL queries?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  MAX(invoiceNo)
FROM
  public.selected_items
WHERE
  LENGTH(invoiceNo) = (
    SELECT 
      MAX(LENGTH(invoiceNo))
    FROM
      public.selected_items
  )
```

It should work for PostgreSQL also.