# MySQL: SUM() of trailing number in VARCHAR

Tags: mysql, regex, string, aggregate-functions

I have a VARCHAR column that contains a bit of text (non-numeric) followed by an integer, e.g. `'foobar: 42'`. I would like to get the SUM() of the numbers, but I can't think of a way to do it.

- If the number was at the beginning, just summing the column would work, but apparently the content has to *begin* with the number. (It didn't throw an error, but I got 0 as a result.)
- If I was sure of the number of leading non-numerics I could use SUBSTRING(), but I can't be sure.
- I thought of using something like LEFT(Column, INSTR(Column, '4')), but I would have to check for any of the ten digits, and I don't see a way to do that.
- REGEXP doesn't appear to help me because it only does matching, not replacement.

Does someone have a clever idea? Yes, I can do a loop in PHP later if I have to, but there are other complexities involved that would get pretty messy if I had to do it that way.

Comment: Is the `:` constant? `select sum(cast(substring(column, instr(column, ':')+1) as signed)) from table;`

Comment: @bishop: Possibly - I prefill the form with it, but it could be overwritten. But also, there might (or might not) be a space after the colon.

Comment: I checked the other thread cited by Álvaro and implemented one of its answers (the one that claims to be faster than the most popular one). I wouldn't have considered it an exact duplicate (I sure didn't find it with a lot of searching effort), but it's close enough. Thanks!

Comment: See also `SUBSTRING_INDEX()`.

Comment: @Rick: Thanks, but that wouldn't have helped in this situation because the character before the number is not guaranteed to be consistent (might be a space, an ASCII colon, a multibyte colon (the users of this usecase are in Japan), or possibly something else.

Comment: SQL is not the best language for cleansing data.  That task should be done in the client code _before_ touching the database.

Comment: I'm not cleansing data - the user can put anything they want in the field, and that's fine. I'm just giving them a chart of summarized results of that data based on some very complicated criteria from joins, and although I could have looped through the data in PHP and kept a running total, it was much easier to do the aggregate in MySQL once I had a way to get the number out of it. As I said above, I have implemented a solution - a UDF that was suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287105/mysql-strip-non-numeric-characters-to-compare by user "wally".