# extract string based on regex for MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex

I have members emailing in for support instead of using the online support form and they are nice enough to put their Member ID into the Subject line. I would like to extract these Member ID from the Subject line to populate the Member ID field for the support ticket.

At the moment, I am able to use something like below to find the tickets where the Subject line has the string pattern which I am looking for (7 numbers in a row). My difficulty now is how to extract these numbers from the Subject line.

```
SELECT t.ID, `Subject`
FROM tickets AS t
WHERE `Subject` REGEXP '[1-6][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]';
```

I have attempted to use the Strip Non Digit function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287105/mysql-strip-non-numeric-characters-to-compare), however, the Subject line may contain other numbers that are not part of the Member ID. How can I extract just the number block that matches that regex?

Comment: MySQL has no built-in function for this. Google for a UDF for regexp replace. Or do it in the client application language.

Comment: Use [this library](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg).