# Is there a way to transform the data before I could query it?

Tags: mysql, regex

MySQL column:

> phone = '(999)-666-333'

> String to search '999666333'

Is there a way I could search by transforming the value '(999)-666-333' within WHERE command?
I want to strip all non-digits and leave only digits.

something like:

```
select * from users where regex(phone, '[0-9]') = '999666333';
```

Comment: You can, but then mysql will not be able to use indexes to look up a value. You better store the phone numbers the way your are going to search on them and either format them for display purposes or store the display value in a separate field.

Comment: I know. unfortunately I already have them stored like that in production (lots of data) and some searches don't work... of course they don't. I'm trying to find a solution how to fix this.

Comment: Add a column which will store the number cleared from all non-digit chars (INT or BIGINT datatype recommended depends on max number length). Update it. Create the index by it and use in your queries. Create triggers which will create/renew this column values during insert/update.

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev that's a good lead, thank you. Dunno why I didn't think of this :)

Comment: @Akina - I reopened this question so you could present your Comment as an Answer.  The "dup" (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287105/mysql-strip-non-numeric-characters-to-compare) specifically says "speed is not an issue".  Furthermore, your comment about using a Trigger is an interesting addition for anyone who does not want the cleanse the data first.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this works in my case:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE REGEXP_REPLACE(phone, '[^0-9]', '') = '999666333';
```