# MySQL column order by alphanumeric ignoring highest value

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, mysql-5.7

In MySQL I have a table named custom_meta where I am getting the values like

```
id   meta_value
1    USNEWYORK01
2    USNEWYORK02
3    USNEWYORK03
4    USNEWYORK04
5    USNEWYORK05
6    USNEWYORK06
7    USNEWYORK07
8    USNEWYORK10
9    USNEWYORK14
10   USNEWYORK16
11   USNEWYORK20
12   USNEWYORK21
13   USNEWYORK32
14   USNEWYORK45
15   USNEWYORK56
16   USNEWYORK78
17   USNEWYORK68
18   USNEWYORK69
19   USNEWYORK80
20   USNEWYORK90
21   USNEWYORK99
22   USNEWYORK100
23   USNEWYORK45
24   USNEWYORK101
```

Now I want to get the meta_value with highest number. So in the table you can see the highest one is `USNEWYORK101`. So to get that I have made query like this

```
SELECT meta_value from custom_meta ORDER BY meta_value DESC LIMIT 1
```

But it is getting `USNEWYORK99` always. I have tried to use `CAST` also but that is also not working.

So can someone help me to get this done? Any suggestions and advice would be really appreciable.

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Get rid of the substring `USNEWYORK` from the `meta_value` column and cast the remaining part as Integer and sort based on that. I will give you the expected output.

Comment: @KamilGosciminski mysql 5.7

Comment: @TejaGoudKandula can you please provide any sample query for that?

Comment: You are ordering by a text value so of course it's ordering alphabetically. 9 sorts above 1. You would be better off normalising your data and storing the numerical part separately which you can then sort by. While the solutions offered work, they are not *sargable* so by storing your sort values as a string you will be incurring a performance hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For newer versions of MySQL you could use `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` function, but since you're using 5.7 we could do it some other way.

Assuming that you always have `USNEWYORK` at the beginning of your values, you could get rid of it, leaving only what comes after that using `SUBSTRING()` function. Then you need to perform `CAST()` to convert text to number values so that sorting works properly.

**Sample data**

```
create table custom_meta(meta_value varchar(255));

insert into custom_meta(meta_value) values
('USNEWYORK01'),('USNEWYORK02'),('USNEWYORK45'),('USNEWYORK99'),('USNEWYORK101');
```

**Solution**

```
select
    meta_value
from
  custom_meta
order by
  cast(substring(meta_value, 10) as unsigned) desc
limit 1
```

**Output**

```
meta_value 
USNEWYORK101
```

Comment: Can't we return only meta_value here? I don't need meta_number here.

Comment: Sure. Check it now.

Comment: This will work with any length of alphanumeric value right? Or is there any restriction?

Comment: Also will this work if tomorrow instead of USNEWYORK any other string will come?

Comment: @NewUser `substring(meta_value, 10)` means get any character starting  from the tenth position , left to right. It will work only if the numbers are from the tenth position left to right, and you do not have any char after or between the numbers

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id,
       meta_value,
       Cast(Substring(meta_value, 10, Length(meta_value)) AS UNSIGNED)
FROM   custom_meta
ORDER  BY 3 DESC
LIMIT  1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace and cast it to int like this:

1. IF Prefix is FİXED to USNEWYORK:

---

```
select * from test 
    order by  CAST(REPLACE(meta_value, "USNEWYORK", "") AS SIGNED) desc;
```

---

2. IF Prefix is not fixed and can be anything , and **mysqldb 8.0**

---

```
select * from test 
    order by  CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(meta_value, '[^0-9]', '') AS SIGNED) desc;
```

---

3. IF Prefix is not fixed and can be anything , and **mysqldb 5.7**
   You can create this function that explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287105/mysql-strip-non-numeric-characters-to-compare) and use it like this:

---

```
select * from test 
        order by  CAST(STRIP_NON_DIGIT(meta_value) AS SIGNED) desc;
```

Comment: @ErgestBasha check again please. I updated

Comment: @ErgestBasha i though USNEWYORK is the only prefix. so prefix can be anything ?

Comment: ok @ErgestBasha. i updtaed. hope it helps